# How does in git move to revision and don't lost anything?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, tortoisegit

Now I have  following structure of `GIT` repository:

[image]

Now I locate at `revision #6`

I want to move to `revision #1`

I afraid to do something because I didn't want to lost revisions 2,3,4,5,6.

Please, help me resolve this issue.

P.S.

I use `tortoise git` or `intellij-idea` for `git` management.

Comment: So, you're currently on the branch 'branch', and this branch's head is at rev 6, right. `git checkout master` will get you back the master, at revision 1. Then `git checkout branch` will switch back to the branch.

Comment: git.exe checkout     master --

terminal-company/src/main/java/com/terminal/dao/impl/TerminalDaoImpl.java: needs merge
terminal-company/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/pages/member/createCompany/addTerminal.jsp: needs merge
error: you need to resolve your current index first

Comment: What is the output of `git status`. Post it in your question.

Comment: @JB Nizet unfortunately I cannot answer this comment because I have already did something and it is working but I didn't understand concrete steps to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout ant random version by using command

```
git checkout SHA1
```

Since those are commits; that means those are either committed by you.
In that case you can recover them by reaching out commits by command

```
git reflog 
git checkout SHA1
```

If those are committed by some else and you have pulled them
you can reset your branch (say master) as follows

```
git fetch 
git reset --hard master origin/master
```

Comment: so he's brand new to git and you are recommending detached head state and hard resets?  That makes no sense.

Comment: That depends on whether or not you think the OP was asking how to go into detached head at SHA1 (it seems unlikely to me that was their goal).  Also, the reflog portion is incorrect, I presume you meant `git log`

Comment: no I meant **git reflog** indeed. If commits are done in current git clone and not pushed yet. If commits are not done in this specific clone that means commits are actually pushed in remote server (example github)  in that case solution #2 applies

Comment: It makes no sense that you would ever want to use reflog instead of log for listing out that history.  Log returns those SHAs no matter how or when they were created.  Reflog has all kinds of failure models.

Answer (score -1):

If you have changes and you don't want to commit them you need to stash your uncommitted work and then you can pull it back in the future.

> git stash
>   git checkout master
>   [do some stuff]
>   git checkout [branch]
>   git stash apply --index

You are now back to where you were

If you have committed then you don't need to stash, just checkout master and then checkout branch once you have done anything you need on master

Comment: [do some stuff] - what the stuff?

Comment: whatever changes you want to make with the master - you can make changes on master and then go back to your branch. The branch will then need to be merged back into master at some point to consolidate all the changes into master

Comment: Don't know why you're giving -1 for this. It answers the question exactly - all you need to do is checkout master but this also protects you from losing any un-committed work